# Quickly Write Vector to File r

Tags: r

What is the fastest way to write a vector to a file? I have a character vector that is ~2 million rows and that has rather large values (200 characters). I am currently doing

```
write(myVector, "myFile.txt")
```

But this is extremely slow. I have searched around for solutions but the fast writing functions (such as `fwrite`) only take a data frame/matrix as input. Thanks!

Comment: You could try `readr::write_lines`? Or you could make the vector a column of a data frame

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After trying several options I found the fastest to be `data.table::fwrite`. Like @Gregor says in his first comment, it is faster by an order of magnitude, which is worth the extra package loaded. It is also one of the ones that produces bigger files. (The other one is `readr::write_lines`. Thanks to the comment by Calum You, I had forgotten this one.)

```
library(data.table)
library(readr)

set.seed(1)    # make the results reproducible
n <- 1e6
x <- rnorm(n)

t1 <- system.time({
    sink(file = "test_sink.txt")
    cat(x, "\n")
    sink()
})
t2 <- system.time({
    cat(x, "\n", file = "test_cat.txt")
})
t3 <- system.time({
    write(x, file = "test_write.txt")
})
t4 <- system.time({
    fwrite(list(x), file = "test_fwrite.txt")
})
t5 <- system.time({
    write_lines(x, "test_write_lines.txt")
})

rbind(sink = t1[1:3], cat = t2[1:3], 
      write = t3[1:3], fwrite = t4[1:3],
      readr = t5[1:3])
#       user.self sys.self elapsed
#sink        4.18    11.64   15.96
#cat         3.70     4.80    8.57
#write       3.71     4.87    8.64
#fwrite      0.42     0.02    0.51
#readr       2.37     0.03    6.66
```

In his second comment, Gregor notes that `as.list` and `list` behave differently. The difference is important. The former writes the vector as one row and many columns, the latter writes one column and many rows.

The speed difference is also noticeable:

```
fw1 <- system.time({
    fwrite(as.list(x), file = "test_fwrite.txt")
})
fw2 <- system.time({
    fwrite(list(x), file = "test_fwrite2.txt")
})

rbind(as.list = fw1[1:3], list = fw2[1:3])
#        user.self sys.self elapsed
#as.list      0.67     0.00    0.75
#list         0.19     0.03    0.11
```

Final clean up.

```
unlink(c("test_sink.txt", "test_cat.txt", "test_write.txt",
         "test_fwrite.txt", "test_fwrite2.txt", "test_write_lines.txt"))
```

Comment: Maybe worth calling out in the first sentence that, not only is `fwrite` fastest, it's fastest by more than 10x. `readr` is faster than `write` and `cat`, but only marginally.

Comment: Also, your `fwrite` code is incorrect, you want `list(x)` not `as.list(x)`. `as.list()` will write a CSV with one row and n columns, (and be a little slower). `list(x)` will give n rows and  1 column.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for the `list()` vs `as.list()` note!

Answer (score 7):

I found `writeBin` to be twice as fast as `fwrite`. Try this:

```
 zz <- file("myFile.txt", "wb")
 writeBin( paste(myVector, collapse="\n"), zz ) 
  close(zz)
```

Using the same timing approach offered by Rui I get (older box):

```
            user.self sys.self elapsed
sink            9.650    7.900  17.418
cat             6.507    7.870  14.254
write           6.436    7.849  14.171
fwrite          0.500    0.051   0.593
write_lines     4.337    0.150   4.451
writeBin        0.238    0.006   0.242
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer - also because you can use "\n" as a separator, instead of fwrite, which is great for outputting csv tables, but it only takes a single character as separator, so you can't use newspace to output, which makes it less useful for a **quick** output of a vector to text file, as OP asked.

Comment: wait, it also puts a weird character at the end of the output: 

^@

which makes my system (endeavour linux ) see it as a binary file. and also, why does it have that? annoying.

Comment: Surprised that `writeBin` results in a binary file? Why? How the end of file appears will depend on the display program, e.g., `hexdump` will display differently than `od` and both will be different than a text editor. On my Linux system there was `0031` displayed with hexdump, and `\00` in one of my text editors (and the text editor warns me that there are "some invalid characters". Turns out those are messages from the low level C program that the EOF was reached, and there isn't an agreed upon standard. https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Comment: Hahaha ok, ok I see your point there lol. thank you for the explanation., God to know I've wondered about those chars and why they often are so different.

Comment: And nice with the detailed blog post I'll make a pdf copy of that to my library

Answer (score 2):

You could use `data.table`'s fwrite:

```
library(data.table) # install if not installed already
fwrite(list(myVector), file = "myFile.csv")
```

Comment: Since OP has a vector, not a list or data frame, you'll need `fwrite(list(myVector), "myFile.csv")`.