# How to extract geojson data stored as a column within a tsv file? (any language or method)

Tags: python, r, csv, geojson

Bing Map released a set of datasets that includes geojson data on roads around the world on the Microsoft github: https://github.com/microsoft/RoadDetections. However, after downloading one of these datasets (the Central Africa file) I noticed that the geojson data is stored within a column within a tsv. I have not been able to convert into a geojson file. How can I extract the geojson data stored the tsv file? (I'm happy to try any language or method).

I've tried handling the data in R by reading the data as a tsv and trying to clean it into a geojson format or reading the data straight as geojson. I have had no luck either way.

Comment: If you start with `dat <- read.table("AfricaCenter-Full.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t", quote="")` and look at the first few, we can see that it is well-formatted json. We can use `lapply(dat$V2, jsonlite::parse_json)` to get the full json structure of each element. How do you intend to use it? I haven't looked through the entire file, but if they are all just single instances of `"LineString"` (however many points per line), then it might be relatively simple to normalize the format a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured it out after testing R's txt export options.  Full props to this page, which lists them:
[Quickly Write Vector to File r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245296/quickly-write-vector-to-file-r)

here's example R code:

```
    dat <- read.table("AmericaCenter-Full.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t", quote="") 
    data3=dat[,2]
    cat(data3, sep="\n", file= "americaCenter_full3.txt")
    #  then go rename that .txt file in Explorer as a .geojson file.  You can also do this in R, but I am answering quickly here.
    library(sf)
    df2=st_read("americaCenter_full3.geojson") #  it opens!
    
    st_write(df2, "americaCenter_full3.gpkg")  #  now convert it to a better file format :)
```